# how to config create react app with worker-loader

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, worker-loader

I need to create an CRA(create-react-app) app with multiple workers. As an example (my workers include import modules):

```
// worker.js
import x from 'file-xxx.js'
addEventListener('message', e => {
   // ...
})
```

```
// App.jsx

App(){
   const mWorker = new Worker('./worker') 
   mWorker.postMessage('data...')

   // ...

}
```

I would like if one help me to construct a simple create react app with above mentioned requirement.

currently I see:

-- https://webpack.js.org/loaders/worker-loader/

-- https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/comlink

-- https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/worker-plugin

Answer (score 0):

can see the following link:
https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra/issues/137

example of usage:
https://github.com/YumcoderCom/yumgram/blob/master/config-overrides.js